# Watch resume event on cordova using ionic framework

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to watch the `resume` event when the app resumes.  I used to have this working but ionic changed things up and now I'm having trouble.  I'm sure it's an easy fix.

This used to work but no longer does:

```
$ionicPlatform.on('resume', function(){
    //rock on
});
```

The [docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/utility/ionic.EventController/) now suggest using the following but I'm not sure which DOM element to use.

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers'])
.run(function() {
    ionic.Platform.ready(function() {
        ionic.on('resume', function(){
            //rock on
        }, element);
    });
});
```

Also, should the `ionic.on()` function be in the `ionic.Platform.ready()` function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, answered my own question.

It didn't change.  I was wrong.  The following works.

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers'])
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        // ready
    });
    $ionicPlatform.on('resume', function(){
        // rock on
    });
});
```

It is unclear in the docs though.  It says [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicPlatform/)

> $ionicPlatform An angular abstraction of ionic.Platform.

so the following should work but it doesn't:

```
ionic.Platform.on('resume', function(){
    // rock on
});
```

Comment: .run(function($ionicPlatform) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        // ready
    });
    $ionicPlatform.on('resume', function(){
        // rock on
    });
});  not triggering on resume event